# How to bind JSON data to Asp.net Text Box control

Tags: asp.net, .net, json

I am trying to bind the `JSON` data to asp.net Text Box control but its not working for me. Where as while binding to `HTML` control like "paragraph tag" it's working fine.

My code is as follows:

```
 <script>
     var text = '{"name":"John Johnson","street":"Oslo West 16","phone":"555 1234567"}';
     var obj = JSON.parse(text);
      document.getElementById("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").val(obj.street);
</script>
```

Please can any one help me out.

Comment: Initially i tried like this

document.getElementById("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").innerHTML = obj.street;

But "innerHTML " is working for Html controls, how can i do it for Asp.net Text Box control.

Comment: You can try this: `document.getElementById("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").value = obj.street`

Comment: thanks @ Mahedi Sabuj